# Excel VLOOKUP Pull Data from several workbooks

Tags: excel-formula, vlookup

Ok so I am tryig to create a Vlookup to look for a user name that is located in 1 of several different workbooks.  If B2 = BOB it will look for BOB in all the worksheets and return the correct value.  There will never by a duplicate of BOB, it will always be a 1 to 1 relationship.

Here was my atempt that is not working at all.

```
=IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP(B3,'[Team 304.xlsx]Data'!$A:$J,4,FALSE)),VLOOKUP(B3,'[Team 304.xlsx]Data'!$A:$J,4,FALSE),IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP(B3,'[Team 302.xlsx]Data'!$A:$J,4,FALSE)),,IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP(B3,'[Team 303.xlsx]Data'!$A:$J,4,FALSE)),,(VLOOKUP(B3,'[Team 301.xlsx]Data'!$A:$J,4,FALSE)))))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid your statement is completely wrong. You have confused the true and false actions and the 'true' actions of the second and third IFs are missing.

Here is the statement restructured :

```
=IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP(B3,'[Team 304.xlsx]Data'!$A:$J,4,FALSE)),
    IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP(B3,'[Team 302.xlsx]Data'!$A:$J,4,FALSE)),
        IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP(B3,'[Team 303.xlsx]Data'!$A:$J,4,FALSE)),
            IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP(B3,'[Team 301.xlsx]Data'!$A:$J,4,FALSE)),
               0,
               VLOOKUP(B3,'[Team 301.xlsx]Data'!$A:$J,4,FALSE)),
            VLOOKUP(B3,'[Team 303.xlsx]Data'!$A:$J,4,FALSE)),
        VLOOKUP(B3,'[Team 302.xlsx]Data'!$A:$J,4,FALSE)),
    VLOOKUP(B3,'[Team 304.xlsx]Data'!$A:$J,4,FALSE))
```

Obviously, you will need to put this on one line to make it work.

Comment: Thank you that works perfect, where do I put in the formula to return 0 if not in any workbook.